# Is there a way to pass statements as a function's parameter?

Tags: python

I'm trying  to make flexible method that can take in statements instead of normal data types. Is there anyway to do this. Here's a simplified example:

```py
def function(*actions):
      for action in actions:
           action     

x = 5
y = 6        

function(x += 10, y *= 2)
```

When I try to run this, Python does not acknowledge (x += 10) or (y *= 2) as valid parameters. Is there a way to achieve what I want without breaking down this function into many smaller ones?

Comment: All the answers are going for the complex solution, but since this guy is very new, it might potentially just be the basics that are required. If so, then it's potentially `function(x + 10, y * 2)` that he'd like.

Comment: Sounds like you want to defer a mathematical computation to a function call while being able to build the expression for the computation a priori? Maybe have a look at [Sympy](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/index.html).

Answer (score 1):

No, but you can pass functions. Note that a function needs to declare if it wants to modify a non-local variable:

```py
x = 5
y = 6

def increase_x():
    nonlocal x
    x += 10

def double_y():
    nonlocal y
    y *= 2

def function(*fs):
    for f in fs:
        f()

function(increase_x, double_y)
```

This is a bit messy because mutating non-local variables is rarely a good idea; it can lead to subtle bugs because it's a lot harder to know where a variable is being modified from. Instead, you can hold the mutable state in a class instance:

```py
class MyThing:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 5
        self.y = 6
    
    def increase_x(self):
        self.x += 10
    
    def double_y(self):
        self.y *= 2

def function(*fs):
    for f in fs:
        f()

my_thing = MyThing()
function(my_thing.increase_x, my_thing.double_y)
```

Comment: thaank you, but I'm trying not to break the function into smaller ones

Answer (score 0):

Python syntax doesn't allow what you want, but there are other ways to achieve something similar.

So, you want to write a function like this:

```py
def function(*actions):
    for action in actions:
        action()
```

So, with that out of the way, to call it, you can only pass in callables.

Here are some examples:

```py
x = 5
y = 6

function(lambda:x+10, lambda: y*2)
```

Unfortunately this doesn't actually accomplish anything.

```py
x = 5
y = 6

def xplus():
    global x
    x += 10
def doubley():
    global y
    y *= 2

function(xplus, doubley)
print(x,y)
```

Output: `15 12`

Comment: thank you, lambdas are exactly what I was looking for

Comment: But, you are aware that with my example of: `lambda:x+10` has no effect on `x`?

Comment: oh I did not know that. Can you explain why it has no effect? I dont want to create new functions to pass into the original

Comment: Yes, `x+10` is just an expression which returns a value without side effects. And a `lambda` is only allowed to contain an expression.

Answer (score -1):

You just want to use [`exec`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#exec):

```py
def function(*actions):
    for action in actions:
        exec(action, globals())

x = 5
y = 6

function("x += 10", "y *= 2")
```

```py
>>> print(f"{x=}, {y=}")
x=15, y=12
```

Comment: No, you *almost* **never** want to use `exec`, **certainly not** while passing `globals()` as context

Comment: The OP did ask for a footgun, who are we to second guess?

Comment: That is not second-guessing, that is plainly providing a dangerous 'solution' (especially if said "actions" are coming from user-input). Plus OP did not ask for a footgun

Comment: @DeepSpace this looks like what I was going for, can you explain why using this would be undesirable?

Comment: It also seems to me that it was what you were looking for. This solution will execute any statement and be able to access the top variables of the module (the `globals()`). As @DeepSpace argues, this is usually quite dangerous, and makes the execution of your program obscure: use it with care!